# Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ClassCastException: class javax.swing.JLabel cannot be cast to class javax.swing.JTextField

Tags: java

this is my code i got no error in compilation but when i try to generate file in my application i got this error title with many errors

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ClassCastException: class javax.swing.JLabel cannot be cast to class javax.swing.JTextField (javax.swing.JLabel and javax.swing.JTextField are in module java.desktop of loader 'bootstrap')
    at projet1.Pdf$5.actionPerformed(Pdf.java:156)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:1972)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2313)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:405)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:262)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:279)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6626)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3389)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6391)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2266)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:5001)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2324)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4833)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4948)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4575)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4516)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2310)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2780)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4833)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:773)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:722)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:716)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:399)
    at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:86)
    at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:97)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$5.run(EventQueue.java:746)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$5.run(EventQueue.java:744)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:399)
    at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:86)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:743)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:203)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:124)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:113)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:109)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:90)
```

this is my code

```
`  

   package projet1;

import java.awt.EventQueue;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;

import org.apache.pdfbox.multipdf.PDFMergerUtility;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.SwingConstants;
import java.awt.Font;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFileChooser;

import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.io.File;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;

public class Pdf extends JFrame {

    private JPanel contentPane;
    private JTextField textpdf;
    private JFileChooser fileChooser;
    private JTextField destField;
    private String destPath;
    private int count = 1;

    /**
     * Launch the application.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    Pdf frame = new Pdf();
                    frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Create the frame.
     */
    public Pdf() {
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setBounds(100, 100, 497, 447);
        contentPane = new JPanel();
        contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));

        setContentPane(contentPane);
        contentPane.setLayout(null);
        
        textpdf = new JTextField();
        textpdf.setBounds(98, 21, 239, 20);
        contentPane.add(textpdf);
        textpdf.setColumns(10);
        
        JLabel lblNewLabel = new JLabel("PDF File");
        lblNewLabel.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 14));
        lblNewLabel.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
        lblNewLabel.setBounds(10, 24, 66, 14);
        contentPane.add(lblNewLabel);
        
        JButton btnParcourir = new JButton("Parcourir");
        btnParcourir.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                fileChooser = new JFileChooser();
                fileChooser.setCurrentDirectory(new File(System.getProperty("user.home")));
                int result = fileChooser.showOpenDialog(contentPane);
                if (result == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
                    File selectedFile = fileChooser.getSelectedFile();
                    textpdf.setText(selectedFile.getAbsolutePath());
                }
            
            }
        });
        btnParcourir.setBounds(347, 20, 89, 23);
        contentPane.add(btnParcourir);
        
        JButton destButton = new JButton("Destination");
        destButton.setBounds(10, 343, 116, 23);
        destButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                fileChooser = new JFileChooser();
                fileChooser.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.DIRECTORIES_ONLY);
                int result = fileChooser.showOpenDialog(contentPane);
                if (result == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
                    File selectedFile = fileChooser.getSelectedFile();
                    destPath = selectedFile.getAbsolutePath();
                    destField.setText(destPath);
                }
            }
        });
        contentPane.add(destButton);
        
        JButton btnAjouter = new JButton("Ajouter");
        btnAjouter.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                count++;
                // ajouter un nouveau label
                JLabel label = new JLabel("PDF File " + count);
                label.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 14));
                label.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
                label.setBounds(10, 24 + (count-1) * 30, 66, 14);
                contentPane.add(label);
                // ajouter un nouveau textfield
                final JTextField textField = new JTextField();
                textField.setBounds(98, 21 + (count-1) * 30, 239, 20);
                textField.setColumns(10);
                contentPane.add(textField);
                // ajouter un nouveau bouton "Parcourir"
                JButton browseButton = new JButton("Parcourir");
                browseButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                        fileChooser = new JFileChooser();
                        fileChooser.setCurrentDirectory(new File(System.getProperty("user.home")));
                        int result = fileChooser.showOpenDialog(contentPane);
                        if (result == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
                            File selectedFile = fileChooser.getSelectedFile();
                            textField.setText(selectedFile.getAbsolutePath());
                        }
                    }
                });
                browseButton.setBounds(347, 20 + (count-1) * 30, 89, 23);
                contentPane.add(browseButton);
                // redimensionner la fenêtre pour s'adapter à la nouvelle ligne
                contentPane.setPreferredSize(
                    new java.awt.Dimension(contentPane.getWidth(), contentPane.getHeight() + 30));
                pack();
                
            }
        });
        btnAjouter.setBounds(10, 374, 89, 23);
        contentPane.add(btnAjouter);
        JButton btnGenerer = new JButton("Generer");
        btnGenerer.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                List<File> filesToMerge = new ArrayList<>();
                
                // Ajouter le fichier PDF initial
                File initialFile = new File(textpdf.getText());
                if(initialFile.exists() && initialFile.isFile()) {
                    filesToMerge.add(initialFile);
                }
                
                // Ajouter les nouveaux fichiers PDF
                for(int i = 2; i <= count; i++) {
                    JTextField textField = (JTextField) contentPane.getComponent(i-1);
                    File file = new File(textField.getText());
                    if(file.exists() && file.isFile()) {
                        filesToMerge.add(file);
                    }
                }
                
                // Fusionner les fichiers PDF
                if(filesToMerge.size() > 1) {
                    try {
                        PDFMergerUtility merger = new PDFMergerUtility();
                        for(File file : filesToMerge) {
                            merger.addSource(file);
                        }
                        merger.setDestinationFileName(destPath + File.separator + "merged.pdf");
                        merger.mergeDocuments(null);
                        
                        // Afficher un message de succès
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(contentPane, "Fusion terminée avec succès ! Le fichier est enregistré dans " + destPath + File.separator + "merged.pdf");
                    } catch (Exception ex) {
                        ex.printStackTrace();
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(contentPane, "Une erreur s'est produite pendant la fusion : " + ex.getMessage());
                    }
                } else {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(contentPane, "Veuillez sélectionner au moins deux fichiers PDF à fusionner.");
                }
            }
        });
        btnGenerer.setBounds(185, 374, 89, 23);
        contentPane.add(btnGenerer);
        
        
        btnGenerer.setBounds(185, 374, 89, 23);
        contentPane.add(btnGenerer);
        
        JButton btnFermer = new JButton("Fermer");
        btnFermer.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                System.exit(0);
            }
        });
        btnFermer.setBounds(347, 374, 89, 23);
        contentPane.add(btnFermer);
        
        destField = new JTextField();
        destField.setBounds(136, 344, 217, 20);
        contentPane.add(destField);
        destField.setColumns(10);
    }
}
`
```

Comment: *at projet1.Pdf$5.actionPerformed(Pdf.java:156)* - the error is on line 156. Don't try to cast a JLabel to a JTextField.

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing is something in the lines of:

```
JLabel label = new JLabel("text");
JTextField field = new JTextField();

field = label;
```

This can't work simply because a JLabel is NOT a JTextField. What you are most likely trying to do, is setting the value from the label in the JTextField:

```
JLabel label = new JLabel("text");
JTextField field = new JTextField();

field.setText(label.getText());
```